# After locking the screen in Ubuntu 14.04, password is not accepted, How can it be fixed?

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, lock-screen

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 fully updated on my laptop.
Since the last update every time I lock the screen (when leaving my room for example) - when I get back and input my password, it is not accepted even though it's the correct password, the error I get is:

```
Password incorrect, please try again
```

I found that clicking the "Switch Account" fixes the issue but it is very annoying, if you know any way to fix it, it would be nice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the several Languages for Keyboard Layout/Input on your system? If you are not sure, I thought it is better to check if it is in different language when you are trying to log in. So rather than `alt`+`shift`(or whatever is set to change your input) you could also to jump to console `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1`, type in there to check, and then come back to GUI `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F7`

Comment: I have another language installed but the language indicator is set correctly to `EN` when I type in the password, jumping to console and logging into the computer using the same password works perfectly, the only way to bypass this issue as far I know is to click the `Switch Account` and then log in.

Comment: try this to reset password,  http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword

Comment: What is the difference between resetting it as root while in multi-user session and while in single user mode?

Comment: Can you try if removing the other language you installed helps? Not a solution at all, but help in identifying the problem.

Comment: Tried it. no luck there.

Comment: Whoever down-voted the question... you could at least say why you decided to down-vote it, anyways, there's a bounty on the question so it doesn't really matter if it's to your liking or not.

Comment: Can you specify what update it was (or updates if you are unsure)?

Comment: I don't know for certain, whenever the update windows pops up and asks for permission to update - I let it, so I can't know for sure which update caused it. I also see that other people are also encountering the same issue so I wonder how come no solution has been found yet.

Comment: It happens also sometime to me even if the correct language is show in the tray. For me it helps to switch the languages back and forth and then I can login again. It strange, but that works.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck finding a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same issue. Very annoying.

Comment: Some answers that address the causes of the same issue are available from this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/509834/lock-screen-does-not-unlock-with-correct-password-gnome-and-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that in some cases the input language is set to Hebrew even though it shows a "EN" icon in the gnome systray, hitting the input language changer sequence does nothing visibly but when I enter the password again it works.

Answer (score 3):

Have the same issue with 16.04.

I know it might not be the perfect solution, but the trick is to simply click on the **switch user** button in the right corner. 
Put in your password and it works.

Comment: I just had this issue on 14.04 suddenly. I tried your suggestion and it worked. I don't know why it did, but thanks!

Comment: This worked from me (Ubuntu 14.04). It is as though the splash page to log in after the screen lock and that after clicking on switch user are two different objects. I realised this because I have customized the desktop background. After switching user, the welcome screen falls back on the original  appearance that it had after reboot, when the correct password was accepted. (This does not imply that customizing your desktop background has any effect on the problem; it just isolates where the problem resides.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but instead of lockimg, you can use switch user screen, and set a shorcut for that.

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shorcuts`, then add a new one. In the "what command to be executed" line, type:

`dm-tool switch-to-greeter`

And then assign your chosen keypresses to it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo chown root /etc/shadow
sudo chmod u=r,g=r /etc/shadow
```

Answer (score -2):

This procedure gives you a full root shell! You can damage your system if you are not careful!

When booting up press SHIFT and use the arrow keys to select the rescue mode option and press enter.

The file system may be read only (it is in all currently supported releases). Remount as read write

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

This will boot the system in rescue mode and you should arrive at a prompt that looks like this

```
root@something
```

To reset your password type this in

```
passwd <username>
```

Press return, then you will be prompted to enter and confirm a new password. 
Once you are done resetting your password you can than switch back to the normal GUI mode by putting this in

```
init 2
```

If if appears to boot normally, but you see a message that says:

```
Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):
```

then you will need a different solution.

Next Option

If the "Standard Way" does not work for you and you recieve the "Give root password for maintenance" message, you can recover your password using the following steps

1. Reboot your computer
2. Press SHIFT or ESC at the grub prompt (as earlier).
3. Select your image.
4. Highlight the line that begins kernel and press 'e' to edit
5. Go to the very end of the line, change the ro to rw and add init=/bin/bash

press enter, then press b to boot your system.

Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.

1. Type in passwd username
2. Set your password.
3. Type in reboot

If this doesn't work I am out of suggestions.

### Correction, my only other suggestion would be a clean install, but this should work.

Comment: I tried it just now but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.
The thing is that I can find people who are experiencing this problem across the internet but couldn't find a solution...