# Is it possible to assign a shortcut to "Switch Account" in the login screen of Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, login-screen

Since I have this problem which is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479345/after-locking-the-screen-in-ubuntu-14-04-password-is-not-accepted-how-can-it-b).
And since the only solution I have for now is to click the "Switch Account" option from the login screen in order to log into my session without getting the "Password incorrect" error then I'm looking for a way to assign a shortcut key to this option, is that possible?

Edit #1:
Once I created the keyboard shortcut, how can I assign a key mapping to it?
As it says in the bottom of the window, I clicked the switch-account row but when I do a key sequence nothing happens:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shorcuts`, then add a new one. In the "what command to be executed" line, type:

`dm-tool switch-to-greeter`

And then assign your chosen keypresses to it.

[image]

[Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1937616)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply, please check Edit #1 in my original question.

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking on the assign keys area? (i.e. Where the Alt+Super+- is in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kh7Ex.png) Also, you have to have a modifier key (or multiple), and then one normal key.

Comment: When I'm in the custom shortcut window I click the line with the new shortcut (right click or left click acts the same) I've created and it pops up the command window, and it keeps saying "Disabled" where the key sequence supposed to be, any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, left click on the word disabled.

Comment: It pops up the command window again and stays in "Disabled"

Comment: I've used Compiz (CCSM) plugin Commands to create the shortcut but it doesn't work, because while the computer is locked the key sequence doesn't work as it belongs to the session which is currently locked... it does not work outside of my user's environment

Comment: Well none of your custom shorcuts will work when in login screen as that is a security vulnerability - I could type Ctrl+Alt+T to open a termnal say...