# Cannot login from lock screen

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, login-screen

On a new 14.04 setup I am having an issue where I cannot login from the lock screen.  When my screen locks, the only way I can login is by selecting to login as a different user, which takes me back to the main login page, then login as myself.  I can also login to one of the shells available using `Ctrl+F#` but this does not help me get back to my workspace.

I tried all the solutions mention in [this similar post](https://askubuntu.com/q/509834/385212) without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that the problem originated from the changes the IT personal at my work put in place to manage a system they are not familiar with. I was not able to narrow down the problem further.  Reinstalling the OS resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your system were shut-down while system update in process.
so I suggest you to login in terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>Alt</kbd>**+**<kbd>F2</kbd>, login to you shell
and execute following command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

it will repair your packages and get your system back.

Comment: I just tried this but it doesn't change anything.  There is no output which makes me think everything is configured.  I can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and the update runs fine and the output from the upgrade command is `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`  When packages have not configured in the past I recall an there was an error when running updates.