# Password does not work after lock

Tags: password, users, user-management

I'm building a new 14.04 box for my family and me.

I learned that the accounts can be transferred by copying `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` from the old box to the new one. Then, I used `rsync` to move the `/home` folders from the old machine to the new one.

Well, I thought I learned.

The odd side effect is that while the password can be used to log in with and various other tasks like SU and software installation, it won't work log back into the desktop after locking the screen (manually or automatically). The only way in after locking is to use the switch user option. Then it will accept the password.

I can only assume Unity has some place they have the password or hash stashed for use here that is now out of sync. Maybe?

Comment: Finally found a post with the answer ...
http://askubuntu.com/questions/509834/lock-screen-does-not-unlock-with-correct-password-gnome-and-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a post with the answer.

```
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/gshadow-
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow
sudo chown root:shadow /etc/shadow-
```

This is outlined at the post ... [Lock screen does not unlock with correct password Gnome and Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509834/lock-screen-does-not-unlock-with-correct-password-gnome-and-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

**try copying these files that configure the screensaver too:**

1. `/etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver`
2. `/etc/gnome/2.18.3/gdm/custom.conf`

Comment: I did not find a /etc/gnome/2.18.3/gdm/custom.conf on either system.

Comment: I copied /etc/pam.d/gnome-screensaver over. still no love. It won't take my password after screen lock.