# Lock Screen Won't Open After Typing In Password

Tags: 20.04, password, lock-screen

I've been using ubuntu 20.04 for about two months now and about a week or two before, when I wake my from suspension and type in the password, the lock won't open. This is now started happening frequently and is very annoying, is there a way I can fix this?

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: Does this help you?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/509834/lock-screen-does-not-unlock-with-correct-password-gnome-and-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I've tried the command but I it would take at a day to test it(as the problem doesn't occur everytime), so I'll let you know then. Thanks

Comment: Same problem here, did anyone figured out how to fix?

Comment: A guy told me to clear all of my cache using stacer. Try the same.