# Are there still issues with re-logging after desktop lock in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: login, 15.04, login-screen

Following [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479345/after-locking-the-screen-in-ubuntu-14-04-password-is-not-accepted-how-can-it-b) in the subject and since no solution has been found:

I was wondering if there are any users of Ubuntu 15.04 which are experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem in both 12.04 and 14.04 following an update.  Further updates appeared to fix the problem.  I recommend you run update a few times.  In the meantime I discovered a stop-gap measure which appears to work.  When this happens, select "log in as other user" (select other user) and then log in as the same user.  Your desktop reappears with all the same programs loaded and no data lost.

Comment: This workaround is already described in my old question but thanks anyways.

Comment: Sorry for not reading your old question as well.  I have been sleep deprived.  I thought I might have something to offer, and in a way I did, in so much as my personal experience is that this problem has both come and gone in my personal experience, as well as those of my friends, and simply through the use of updates and patience.